# Replace a value of a numpy array with infinty

Tags: python, numpy, infinity

Suppose I have the following numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import inf

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

And I want to replace the j-th index of that array with infinity, e.g

```
x[2] = inf
```

Is there any way of acchieving this? Because when I try that I get the following error:

```
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert your array to float using dtype parameter in the constructor or using `arr.astype(np.float32)` before assigning the inf like below

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import inf

x = np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype=np.float32)
x[2] = inf
```

Answer (score 1):

while declaring the array declare it like this : `np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype='f')`, `inf` in `numpy` is of type *float*.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using an 'int' array.

By defining the array to

```
 x = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])
```

Or:

```
 x = np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype='f')
```

You won't have any problem to do it correctly.

Internally, 'inf' is a float const and it doesn't support int type.

```
np.iinfo(np.int32).max  # ---- 2147483647

np.iinfo(np.int32).min  # ---- -2147483648

np.iinfo(np.int64).max  # ---- 9223372036854775807

np.iinfo(np.int64).min  # ---- -9223372036854775808
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You can convert your array to float type.

```py
x = np.array([0,1,2], dtype=np.float32)
```

Then you can assing infinity number using np.inf

**2.** You can also set as infinity maximum number of the integer.

```py
ii16 = np.iinfo(np.int16)
x[2] = ii16.max
```

In the second approach you have to specify which of ineger you use in your code.